# How to set image and text on JRadioButton?

Tags: java, image, swing, text, jradiobutton

I am using Swing and `JRadioButton` in my application. I need to set image and text on my button.  For that I am using this:

```
JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("text", iconpath, false);
```

But what it giving output is it's hiding radio button and just showing the image.

How to over come this problem, any suggestion? and can we Create something for similar problem for JCheckbox too?

Comment: The icon overrides the "radio" button thingy in place of the usual circle.  I tend to use a `JLabel` to hold the icon and text, depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: I want that circle text and image too. shown into that.

Comment: Yep, create a `JRadioButton`, no text or icon.  Create a `JLabel` with the icon and text. Set the label's `labelFor` property, add the two together onto your screen.  You might find it easier adding them a `JPanel` first.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But what i am doing is i need to add it dynamically m not dragging that components. what if i need that text value onclick and i need to click that Radiobutton on text click.

Comment: Then keep and association of the radio button and label, may be even create a custom component

Comment: @MadProgrammer Custom Component? how to do that? and ya can i have example bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the icon of a `JRadioButton` or `JCheckBox` replaces the default glyph used by these controls - I know, annoying.

The simplest solution is to simply create a `JLabel` which can be associated with the `JRadioButton`, perhaps using some kind of `Map` to maintain the linkage between

A more, long term solution, might be to create a custom component which marries the concept into a custom and re-usable component, for example...

```
public class XRadioButton extends JPanel {

    private JRadioButton radioButton;
    private JLabel label;

    public XRadioButton() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(getRadioButton());
        add(getLabel());
    }

    public XRadioButton(Icon icon, String text) {
        this();
        setIcon(icon);
        setText(text);
    }

    protected JRadioButton getRadioButton() {
        if (radioButton == null) {
            radioButton = new JRadioButton();
        }
        return radioButton;
    }

    protected JLabel getLabel() {
        if (label == null) {
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setLabelFor(getRadioButton());
        }
        return label;
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        getRadioButton().addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        getRadioButton().removeActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        getLabel().setText(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return getLabel().getText();
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
        getLabel().setIcon(icon);
    }

    public Icon getIcon() {
        return getLabel().getIcon();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well i never use this let me try once.

Comment: @Mad there isn't real Icon, is L&F sensitive, should be paintIcon :-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer its working yar. really how do u know this much. i dont know even how u create it. :P

Comment: +1 And Accept to this ans yar. to A Really "Mad" Programmer. :P :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can we Make it same thing for JcheckBox too??

Comment: Sure, change `JRadioButton` to `JCheckBox`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okey M trying :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer hey its done i created but trying to implement if u dont mind asking u some doubts if i face in that.:)

Comment: Does this mean we can click on the JLabel and it will trigger the action of the JRadioButton? 
Or will clicking on the JLabel do nothing.

Comment: @AbhiTk In this example, no, but it wouldn't be difficult to add a `MouseListener` either to the label to the panel itself and trigger the radio buttons `doClick` method